# Magento is not sending confirmation after B2B registration

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I have a Magento website that has b2b registration enabled. When I visit the link  `www.mysite.com/b2b` it gives the ability of registration and after the customer clicks on submit a message pops up that says **You will receive a confirmation e-mail**. The e-mail never arrives though. Where could the problem be?  Thank you in advance

Comment: check you are configured cron correctly. also check mail are send to spam

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I needed to access the admin panel and then **Customers->Manage Customers** and then **Account->Information** and then expand the **Is Confirmed** menu and change it to **Confirmed**. Also check the box about sending welcome. After that, depending on the Cron, the B2B client receives the confirmation e-mail.